# Can't update to latest PHP version. Centos 7

Tags: linux, php, security, redhat

I'm unable to update to the latest PHP package.  I ran `yum update php` and it updated to PHP 5.4.16. Reran the update command to see if there was any newer versions and stated there was no packages marked to update. 5.4.16 is over a year old and is exposed to many vulnerabilities so would like to update to the latest. Any advice on how I can overcome this?

Comment: I think it's a valid question....

Answer (score 5):

From their FAQ (http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-472ce8446ebcfc82ca1800f775ba0e629ac835c7):

> 22. Where can I get the latest version of XyZ.rpm for CentOS? I cannot find it anywhere.
>
> CentOS is an Enterprise-class operating system and as such is more about stability and long-term support than cutting edge. Major package versions are retained throughout the life cycle of the product. This is generally what Enterprise wants and affords developers a stable base on which to develop without fear that bespoke applications will break every time something gets upgraded to the latest and greatest, but ultimately buggy version or the API changes breaking backwards compatibility.
>
> So no, you will generally NOT find the very latest versions of various packages included in an Enterprise-class operating system such as CentOS. It's a feature not a deficiency.

About security: security patches are backported. That is point 23. in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

[Webtatic](https://webtatic.com) has [php 5.6.3](https://webtatic.com/news/2014/11/latest-updates-in-testing-26/) available, which was released [this month](http://php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-11-13-2):

UPDATE:

> yum update php56w --enablerepo=webtatic-testing

INSTALL:

> rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm rpm -Uvh
> https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
>
> yum install php56w

You can always rollback if needed with [yum-plugin-replace](https://iuscommunity.org/pages/IUSClientUsageGuide.html) available via [ius repos](https://iuscommunity.org):

> yum replace --enablerepo=webtatic-testing php56w-common
> --replace-with=php-common